# InvalidRequest when copying file in onedrive

Tags: python, copy, onedrive

When copying a file in onedrive, I get the following error:

```
onedrivesdk.error.OneDriveError: invalidRequest - ObjectHandle is Invalid
```

This error occurs only when copying to the root file, otherwise it works just fine.

This is how the code looks like:

```
ref = onedrivesdk.ItemReference()
ref.id = 'root'
client.item(drive='me', id='itemtocopy!id').copy(parent_reference=ref).post()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I still don't know what causes the problem, but i found a workaround.
The key is to use ref.path instead of ref.id.

Instead of `ref.id = 'root'`, I used `ref.path = '/drive/items/root'`, and it works just the same.

Anyway, I'd still like to hear if someone can explain this.